# How can I retrieve the result value from stripe.redirectToCheckout()?

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I am trying to get the result value from
a stripe.redirectToCheckout(). It is said to return a Promise https://stripe.com/docs/js/checkout/redirect_to_checkout.
Here is the code that I thought would work but it doesn't

```
    stripe.redirectToCheckout({
      lineItems: [
        {
          price: stripePrice,
          quantity: token,
        },
      ],
      mode: "payment",
      successUrl: someurl
      cancelUrl: someurl
    }).then(result => {
        if (result.error) {
            alert(result.error.message);
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both client-only Checkout and `redirectToCheckout` are no longer recommended.

Instead you can use [Payment Links](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-links) (if you need a client-only solution) or you can create Checkout Sessions on your server and send people to [the `url` on the Checkout Session object](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-url).

Regarding your original question, though, `redirectToCheckout` will only return a promise if the redirect fails.  If the redirect succeeds the JavaScript running on your page will stop running because the browser will have navigated to another page (the Stripe Checkout page), so there's no chance for anything to be returned.

Comment: Well, the guys that gave me that assignment don't like the idea of a server.

Comment: Payment Links don't require a server. 

Comment: Okay, I will check them out. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can't get data out of this function as you are redirected and your script ceases to exist

Stripe wile redirect you back after user checkout and then you have to read the data.

Comment: How do I read the data from stripe after the checkout?

Comment: I'm not sure, but https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/custom-success-page seems like checkout session should have  the data you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can add session_id query param to get checkout data:

1. Modify the success URL:

```js
success_url: "http://yoursite.com/order/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}"
```

Note that `CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID` is a literal string and must be added exactly as you see it here.

2. Use session_id to get checkout data:

```js
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.retrieve(req.query.session_id);
const customer = await stripe.customers.retrieve(session.customer);
```

Source: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/custom-success-page